# Linking back from child HTML to parent HTML embedded in div

Tags: javascript, html, parent-child

I have a portion of a child HTML file called up inside a div using an id tag in the parent. I want to create a button to clean out the child content and return to the parent inside that div. What would the JS code be for this, for a graphic?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. You are loading a html page inside a div (iframe?) and want to remove it when you click on a button?

Comment: Show some effort on your end first. E.g. put up something in a [New JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and post the link to it here. Describe where you are struggling in as small a test-case as possible.

Comment: @RonenDex, yes, I'm loading an html page inside a div (not iframe) and want to remove it when clicking a button, and have it return to the prior content in the parent html.

Comment: @RonenDex I created a new question thread @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20579323/link-back-out-from-child-html-loaded-in-div-to-parent-html

Answer (score 0):

suppose your html is:

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='innerParent'>
     <input type='button' id='removeChildContent'>
     <div class='child'>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

so, using jQuery, you can clean the child content as below:

```
$(function()
{
 $('#removeChildContent').click(function()
 {
  $(this).siblings().not(':first').remove();//removes the child elements of inner parent, except this button
 })
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried implementing this but no success. I created a new question thread that lays everything out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20579323/link-back-out-from-child-html-loaded-in-div-to-parent-html